# horizontal align image to dropdown using css background

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a container that is a popup over a page and it has many controls one of them is a dropdown, now I would like to make this dropdown load dynamically, for which I need to add an icon next to the dropdown when it is loading.

How can i achieve the same using css specifically using the background property.. Is that the best solution?

Also I need my dropdown width to update once the dropdown content is loaded and the image disappears..

I am struggling to get the image on the page next to the dropdown..

here is a fiddle that I have created: http://jsfiddle.net/jxWCu/1

now I want to have the image horizontally aligned with the dropdown..

Comment: created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jxWCu/1 I was creating one when you asked for it.. :d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select box and loading image need to be separate entities. Also, I do not suggest using a 320x320 gif. http://jsfiddle.net/jxWCu/11/

Comment: is there no other way? The reason I want them on the dropdown is cos I need to adjust the widht of the dropdown once the drodown is loaded, my idea was to remove this class entirely and another default class would apply

Comment: The drop-down should auto-resize based on its content. Since both items are `float:left` the loading icon will move with the width of the dropdown. see Update: http://jsfiddle.net/jxWCu/12/

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the loading styles to the container div http://jsfiddle.net/jxWCu/7/

Comment: I have other controls in my container

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to style the drop down itself so you can just add this in it's own div in your container. That way you're other controls won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

CSS pseudo-elements might make for a neat solution here too: [ http://jsfiddle.net/jxWCu/14/ ]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="loading">
    <select> 
        <option>Loading</option>
    </select>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.loading select { width: 260px; } /* Width of your dropdown */
.loading:after {
    content: url(http://ajaxload.info/cache/FF/FF/FF/00/00/00/1-0.gif);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: how do I get rid of the style using javascript?

Comment: You could just use JavaScript to set the 'loading' class to have "content: none;" to remove the image.

Comment: @user917670 Don't forget to mark whichever answer you felt answered your question the best as correct.